# MySQL - selecting first 3rd, second 3rd, and third 3rd from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Given table1, table2, and table3 (assume they are identical in structure), is it possible to select the first 1/3 records of table1, table2, and table3? Then the second 1/3? Then the last 1/3?

Comment: Tough one But can be done. Using stored procedure limit and dynamic sql.. Because limit does not not facilitate for variable so we need a prepared statement which is only available in procedures

Comment: How are you definining "the first 1/3 records".  Tables are inherently unordered, so there is no concept of the first record in the table.

Comment: It is not possible straightforward. However possible after a bounty perhaps :)... I am near to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first 1/3 record**:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
       SELECT * FROM Table1 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT * FROM Table2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * FROM Table3 
       UNION ALL
    ) sub
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t 
ORDER BY Id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

**The second 2/3::**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
       SELECT * FROM Table1 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT * FROM Table2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * FROM Table3 
       UNION ALL
    ) sub
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t 
ORDER BY Id ASC
LIMIT 2, 1
```

**The last 1/3 record:**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
       SELECT * FROM Table1 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT * FROM Table2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * FROM Table3 
       UNION ALL
    ) sub
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t 
ORDER BY Id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with a LIMIT and a OFFSET clause like :

```
SELECT column FROM table1 LIMIT X OFFSET Y
union
SELECT column FROM table2 LIMIT X OFFSET Y+10
union
SELECT column FROM table3 LIMIT X OFFSET Y+20
```

but you must parameterize the LIMIT and the OFFSET.. that's a way